# Why does react-modal require the prop contentLabel?

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

I started getting this warning on my react-modal components:

> Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `contentLabel` was not
>   specified in `Modal`.

It doesn't prevent the modal from working correctly, I just see the warning in the dev tools console. I can pass this prop in by specifying some random string, but I do not understand what this is actually used for, and why it is required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`contentLabel` improves accessibility. You probably don't notice it, but in certain situations this `prop` can help your users understand what the modal is about. From [their repository](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal#usage):

> The Modal object has two required props:
>
> - `isOpen` to render its children.
> - `contentLabel` to improve a11y, since `v1.6.0`.

The value of `contentLabel` is set as an [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) on the modal element. This helps [assistive technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_technology), like screen readers, to add a label to an element that would otherwise be anonymous. People with visual impairment for example can make more sense out of your modal when added.

Comment: Yes, I saw that piece of documentation, but it does not exactly explain why it is required. So it is some sort of aid to users. I imagined that it did somehow, and no I did not notice it, so the question is, how does it help precisely?

Comment: In what situations does it help? I saw the documentation but it does not say anything other than what you pasted above.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In thishttps://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/blob/master/dist/react-modal.js  contentLabel and isOpen is set required like this   contentLabel: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired if you remove .isRequired then you can use modal without defining contentLabel prop.

Comment: I am aware I can go to the actual package and modify it, but I don't want to modify it, I just want to understand what the logic was of making it required. I don't believe it was required in older versions of react-modal.

Comment: This is because of arial lable. aria-label does much the same thing like lable, but it's for those cases where it isn't practical or desirable to have a label on screen.